# Why is a scrypt hash different each time?

Tags: hash, python, scrypt

I'm trying to wrap my mind around `scrypt` and how it's hashing works. I've got a basic function that will create a `scrypt` hash, however it seems that everytime I run it, the hash is different. Does `scrypt` always output a different hash, if so, why?

```
from passlib.hash import scrypt

def scrypt_hash(string, salt=None, front=False, back=False):
    print scrypt.hash(string)

#<= $scrypt$ln=16,r=8,p=1$3RvjfE9JCWEMobT2HoPQ+g$fv0toINPck6zSYD5+QqKUFi4GkptYT/deJ/C8R0JLSU
#<= $scrypt$ln=16,r=8,p=1$Xus9x/g/p1QK4bzX+p9zLg$G/JbYOw8Km1l57MUescXrPEjbVz8GIh8lPyIlOI9rMc
#<= $scrypt$ln=16,r=8,p=1$qzXGOIew1npvzZnzvpdSqg$17/frDtJOPnOODHSXOM4kw6N3oUNLltLOTf+odzZ8RA
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't specify a salt, one is randomly generated. The salt is different each time, so the hash will also be different.

> salt (str) – Optional salt string. If specified, the length must be between 0-1024 bytes. If not specified, one will be auto-generated (this is recommended).

[source](http://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.scrypt.html?highlight=scrypt)

Comment: So there is not way to produce a script hash without salt?

Comment: You would never want to produce an scrypt digest without a salt; such a design would have no resistance to precomputation attacks like rainbow tables.